# SOLR sorting based on date : storing date as toISOString(), whereas toUTCString fails

Tags: node.js, solr, full-text-search

During storing date field into SOLR, I convert Date() to toISOString() and it accepts. I tried storing using toUTCString, but it fails.

Now while searching, I am sorting based on date, I do get result, but these are not sorted in an descending order, rather I get it in mixed order.

I tried specifying a range, using [NOW-1YEAR/DAY TO NOW/DAY+1DAY], but the result is still the same. First I get 6 days old document, then 30min old doc and then 2 months old doc.

what should be the right approach ?

EDIT:
Here is the date field that i added in schema.xml

```
   <field name="message_date" type="date" indexed="true" stored="false" />
```

and here are the parameters, I am sending during each search,

```
query = "*:*";
var options = {
            fq: '{!geofilt}',
            sfield: 'location',
            pt: latitude+','+longitude,
            d: 10,
            sort: ["message_date desc", "geodist() asc"],
            start: 0,
            rows: 10
        }

solrclient.query(query, options, function(err, solrRes){
....
});
```

This is javascript in the server side, node.js code.

Comment: What sort of field type are you using for the date? Also, could you update your question with the relevant portions of your config files? Thanks.

Comment: Andrew I updated the question. Please let me know if I need to provide any other details.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I found the problem. The above code is fine and it is working. Problem was, after retrieving the result from SOLR, I do a finer search in my database to get more details and that was not sorted. That created the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code is fine and it is working. Problem was, after retrieving the result from SOLR, I do a finer search in my database to get more details and that was not sorted.
So sorted the result from Mongodb after retrieving the result from SOLR and that worked.

Using nodejs and the solr module is, https://github.com/gsf/node-solr